# Enquiry on systems with complex temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

In statistical mechanics, what does it really mean for a system to have complex temperature ? What is the significance of the real and imaginary parts of the temperature ?

Comment: @Countto10, the question whose link you copy and pasted seems to mention nothing about the significance of the real and imaginary parts of the temperature, which is my main question.

Comment: True enough, the only reference  regarding complex involves imaginary time, which is a bit vague unless more details are given. My apologies, I will delete my comment and upvote. But it might be a good idea to say where you have looked already, as a one line question may be seen as a lack of research. Best of luck with it.

Comment: @Count010, thank you very much. The undergraduate texts in statistical mechanics that i read seem not to contain anything about systems with complex temperature, and the top suggestion that shows up after a google search is the question in your link...

Comment: My guess  is that this will leave you with a headache: https://arxiv.org/pdf/nucl-th/0501041v2.pdf   If I can find a better reference I will, but it seems to relatedto expressing the partition function as a complex function, so that two real "ordinary" variables can be treated more easily, an analogy would be the use of complex numbers in electromagnetism. Apologies if you already know this though.

Comment: @Countto10, thank you very much. I will look into that paper.

Comment: Unsolicited Advice: I think I am on the right track about the partition function: https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9711058v1.pdf  I would consider putting the abstract of this above article in your post _We calculate complex-temperature (CT) zeros of the partition function
for the q-state Potts model on the honeycomb and kagom ́e lattices for
several values of q. These give information on the CT phase diagrams. A comparison of results obtained for different boundary conditions and a d
iscussion of some CT singularities are given._

Comment: The distribution of complex zeros of the partition function, seen as a function of a complex inverse temperature $\beta$, usually called *Fisher zeros*, provides information on analytic properties of the free energy. This is completely analogous to the analysis of the complex zeros of the partition function, seen as a complex function of the *magnetic field*, that was initiated by Lee and Yang in their famous 1952 paper.

Comment: In this setting, the imaginary component of the inverse temperature (or magnetic field in the Lee-Yang case) has no special physical interpretation. (In some cases, there seems to be some interpretation in the case of complex magnetic field, see [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.010601) for example).